# G-Mail logging me out unexpectedly

Tags: gmail, google-account

> **Problem:** When I sign into two G-Mail accounts while using Chrome and then close the window, I'm logged out of both G-Mail accounts. Is there a way to prevent the forceful logout?

For the things I've tried and any relevant information I can think of...

- I use a company laptop
- I know it's specific to Chrome because I can use Firefox under the same conditions and am not logged out (so it isn't a company/institution policy).
- I remain logged in when I sign into only one of the two accounts and proceed to close the window (it doesn't matter which account; I tested both and remained logged in)
- A quick search on Google yielded some simple tricks about adjusting settings for cookies within Chrome, but these didn't make any difference
- The issue started semi-recently, maybe a month ago; prior to this, Chrome kept me logged in

Is there anything I can do to the settings (or otherwise) to correct the behavior?

Comment: As you are using a company laptop, check if Chrome is being administered by your company, if so, contact your company IT support.